# Why is the Groovy method minus() so slow with lists of numbers?

Tags: list, groovy, time-complexity, set-difference

Let's say I have two lists `left` and `right` of size *n*, each with unique integers, and I want to find the intersection and differences. This should be able to be done in *O(n)* or *O(nlog(n))*. This is how I instantiate the lists:

```groovy
Integer n = 10_000
Integer overlap = (Integer) (0.1 * n)
List left = (1..n).toList().shuffled()
List right = (n-overlap+1..2*n-overlap).toList().shuffled()
```

One way to get the intersection and differences would be for example:

```groovy
Set setLeft = left

Set onlyInRight = right.findAll { !(it in setLeft) }
Set inBoth = right.findAll { !(it in onlyInRight) }
Set onlyInLeft = left.findAll { !(it in inBoth) }
```

This works quite well, but I find the following more readable:

```groovy
List inBoth = left.intersect(right)
List onlyInLeft = left - inBoth
List onlyInRight = right - inBoth
```

Interestingly, when I played around a bit the latter apporach was pretty slow and felt more like *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. So I took a peek at the [code base](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java) of the [minus method](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#minus(java.util.Collection)):

```groovy
public static <T> Collection<T> minus(Iterable<T> self, Iterable<?> removeMe, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        Collection<T> self1 = asCollection(self);
        Collection<?> removeMe1 = asCollection(removeMe);
        Collection<T> ansCollection = createSimilarCollection(self1);
        if (self1.isEmpty())
            return ansCollection;
        T head = self1.iterator().next();

        boolean nlgnSort = sameType(new Collection[]{self1, removeMe1});

        // We can't use the same tactic as for intersection
        // since AbstractCollection only does a remove on the first
        // element it encounters.

        if (nlgnSort && (head instanceof Comparable)) {
            //n*LOG(n) version
            Set<T> answer;
            if (head instanceof Number) {
                answer = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
                answer.addAll(self1);
// ------------ Beginning of relevant part --
                for (T t : self1) {                     // A) -- loop over self1
                    if (t instanceof Number) {
                        for (Object t2 : removeMe1) {   // B) -- inner loop over removeMe1
                            if (t2 instanceof Number) {
                                if (comparator.compare(t, (T) t2) == 0)
                                    answer.remove(t);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (removeMe1.contains(t))
                            answer.remove(t);
                    }
                }
// ------------ End of relevant part --
            } else {
                answer = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
                answer.addAll(self1);
                answer.removeAll(removeMe1);
            }

            for (T o : self1) {
                if (answer.contains(o))
                    ansCollection.add(o);
            }
        } else {
            //n*n version
            // ...
```

The relevant part is between the comments (from me)

- `// -- Beginning of relevant part --` and
- `// -- End of relevant part --`.

Is it just me or is this *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* for `instance of Number`? Maybe there is a reason for this, but instead, I would have expected something like

```groovy
// ------------ Beginning of relevant part --
                for (Object t : removeMe1) {
                    answer.remove(t);
                }
// ------------ End of relevant part --
```

So if I am not mistaken `minus()` works faster if I wrap the numbers in a custom value class implementing `Comparable`. Has anybody an idea what I am missing or why it was implemented like this?

Comment: Integer is implementing comparable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Integer also extends Number and therefore `t instanceof Number == true` and as I understand it the inner loop B) is executed, resulting in `O(n^2 log(n))` in total. For objects that implement comparable but do not extend Number, this would only be `O(n log(n))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul King answered instantly in [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10964). Short version in my own words:

If you have different types of numbers in a list, Groovy's `minus()` is clever and tries to remove all objects of the same mathmatical value regardless of type. Equality checks are needed, hence *O(n<sup>2</sup> log(n))*.

Example:

```
assert [1, 2, 2.0f, 2.0G] - [2.0d, 1.0G] == []
```

If you do not want this behaviour you can use the Java streams solution from @dagget or the example using Sets in the question.

Answer (score 2):

you could raise a ticket here https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GROOVY/issues with question "why" or you could even suggest a new solution for "minus" method

---

NOT OK:

casting lists to arrays is not helping much

```
Integer[] inBoth = left.intersect(right).toArray() // <<<===
List onlyInLeft = left - inBoth
List onlyInRight = right - inBoth
```

---

implementation using java streams quite fast

```
Integer n = 10_000
Integer overlap = (Integer) (0.1 * n)
var left = (1..n).toList().shuffled()
var right = (n-overlap+1..2*n-overlap).toList().shuffled()

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
Object[] diff2(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right){
    List<Integer> inBoth = left.stream().filter(right::contains).toList()
    List onlyInLeft = left.stream().filter{!inBoth.contains(it)}.toList()
    List onlyInRight = right.stream().filter{!inBoth.contains(it)}.toList()
    return [onlyInLeft, onlyInRight]
}


def t = System.currentTimeMillis()
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    def (onlyInLeft, onlyInRight) = diff2(left, right)
    def actual = onlyInRight.size()
    assert actual == n - overlap
}
println("t = ${(System.currentTimeMillis()-t)/1000} s")
"OK"
```

Comment: Thanks! I already have requested a Jira account;-) Regarding your workaround: I guess there is a `.toArray()` missing at the end of line 3 of your code. If I'm getting it right the `minus()` method on arrays (for length > 1) creates lists out of the arrays and then uses the same `minus()` method I was complaining about :-)

Comment: It's enough to convert to array only `inBoth` to make code much faster.

Comment: If you want to remove the array from the list using `minus()`, Groovy treats the array as a single object. It will be much faster, but the list will not be changed. Could you verify: `assert onlyInLeft.size() == n - overlap` and `assert onlyInRight.size() == n - overlap`

Comment: you are right. check the updated option.